# Why can't I open a webbrowser with webbrowser.open("www.python.org") on Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, browser, cygwin

```
>>> webbrowser.open("www.python.org")
False
```

Is there any other way to get the same functionality of that function in Cygwin?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, did you try `webbrowser.open("http://www.python.org")`?

Comment: @Lanaru: Yep, `webbrowser.open("http://www.python.org")` also returns `False`.

Comment: Sounds kind of like [this Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1244861), which contains a patch but no-one to test it...

Comment: Downvotes are probably because you left out crucial information like what version of Python and Cygwin you are using, which web browser you are using, etc.

Comment: @Hoffman Ow, I'm sorry. I used Python 2.7.3 on Cygwin 1.7.16 and tried Firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching a web browser from Cygwin can be done through

```
cygstart "http://www.google.com"
```

where *google.com* is your desired URL.

*cygstart* launches the default windows program for a path, so this way you get the user’s preferred web browser.

So in Python under Cygwin you might just:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["cygstart", "http://www.google.com"])
```

or [try another option from here to run the Python-external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).

If it's not just a one-off script you are writing for your own use, you should use [`platform.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.system) to use the above on Cygwin, and `webbrowser.open` on other platforms.

Answer (score 13):

```
export BROWSER=cygstart
```

before starting Python. Then it should work.

Comment: Works!  It is even possible to assign the "BROWSER" env. var. in the Python script if doing `import os; os.environ['BROWSER'] = 'cygstart'` **before** `import webbrowser`.

Comment: Python 3.4.1 does not need changes to "BROWSER" env. var., but e.g. 3.2 did, so looks like the issue has been addressed.

Comment: I submitted a patch to fix this almost 10 years ago, ["Enable `os.startfile` and `webbrowser.WindowsDefault` on Cygwin"](http://bugs.python.org/issue1244861). It was never accepted. I don't know what changed in Python 3.4.1 but if this works now, I'm glad.

Comment: Suppose if you don't want set 'BROWSER' env variable, adding following snipper should help,

`webbrowser.register('cygstart', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('cygstart'), -1)`